# AVAssetWriter getting raw bytes makes corrupt videos on device (works on sim)

Tags: cgcontext, avassetwriter

So my goal is to add `CVPixelBuffers` into my `AVAssetWriter` / `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` with *super high speed*. My previous solution used `CGContextDrawImage` but it is very slow (0.1s) to draw. The reason seems to be with color matching and converting, but that's another question I think.

My current solution is trying to read the bytes of the image directly to skip the draw call. I do this:

```
CGImageRef cgImageRef = [image CGImage];
CGImageRetain(cgImageRef);
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImageRef);
CGDataProviderRetain(dataProvider);
CFDataRef da = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL,
                             CGImageGetWidth(cgImageRef),
                             CGImageGetHeight(cgImageRef),
                             kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                             (void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(da),
                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImageRef),
                             NULL,
                             0,
                             NULL,
                             &pixelBuffer);
[writerAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentTime];    
-- releases here --
```

This works *fine* on my simulator and inside an app. But when I run the code inside the SpringBoard process, it comes out as the images below. Running it outside the sandbox is a requirement, it is meant for jailbroken devices.

I have tried to play around with e.g. pixel format styles but it mostly comes out with differently corrupted images.

The proper image/video file looks fine:
[image]
But this is what I get in the broken state:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I think I got the answer(s). The resolution difference was a simple code error, not using the device bounds on the latter ones.

The color issues. In short, the CGImages I got when running outside of the sandbox was using more bytes per pixel, 8 bytes. The images I get when running inside the sandbox was 4 bytes. So basically I was simply writing the wrong data into the buffer.

So, instead of simply slapping all of the bytes from the larger image into the smaller buffer. I loop through the pixel buffer row-by-row, byte-by-byte and I pick the RGBA values for each pixel. I essentially had to skip every other byte from the source image to get the right data into the right place within the buffer.